# Wind Data for Newfoundland or New Brunswick

Tags: data, arcgis-10.2, canada

I am looking for wind data at an elevation of 100 metres for Newfoundland and New Brunswick that I can potentially bring into ArcGIS 10.2.2 to augment my wind turbine siting process.

Any information and links would be quite helpful.

Comment: http://www.windatlas.ca/en/faq.php

Comment: That data are not routinely collected at Canadian Weather stations, they obviously had access to non-public information